# Execute sql query in php

Tags: php, mysql

Can someone help me please to grab data from a mysql table. i would like to execute calculation regarding the Activity field value. the sql query work but i can not apply it in a php page. 
Thank you so much i just changed the query structure code, it still can not work, what do yo see:

```
<?php 
include_once('mysql_workbench.php'); 
$qryz="SELECT  Agent, Activity, format((PreTaxSalary), 2) as PreTaxSalary,    
format((TransactionNum), 2) as TransactionNum 

CASE attr(Activity)
When 'Eligibility Only (DDS)'
Then 
IF sum(TransactionNum)< 2206
Then sum(TransactionNum)*6.81
ElseIF sum(TransactionNum)< 2706
Then ((sum(TransactionNum)-2205)*6.95)+ (2205*6.81)
ElseIF sum(TransactionNum)< 3206
Then ((sum(TransactionNum)-2705)*7.25) + (500*6.95) + (2205*6.81) 
Else ((sum(TransactionNum)-3205)*7.85)+ (500*7.25) + (500*6.95)
+(2205*6.81)

END 
When 'EOB posting'
Then 
IF sum(TransactionNum)< 1786
Then sum(TransactionNum)*8.41
ElseIF sum(TransactionNum)< 2786
Then ((sum(TransactionNum)-1785)*9)+ (1785*8.41)
ElseIF sum(TransactionNum)< 3786
Then ((sum(TransactionNum)-2785)*9.75) + (1000*9) + (1785*8.41) 
Else ((sum(TransactionNum)-3785)*10.5)+ (1000*9.75) + (1000*9) +   
(1785*8.41)
END

When 'Trainee-1'
Then AVG(PreTaxSalary)*sum(TransactionNum)
When 'Trainee-1'
Then AVG(PreTaxSalary)*sum(TransactionNum)
When 'Trainee-2'
Then AVG(PreTaxSalary)*sum(TransactionNum)

END

from  payroll_trial group by Agent ";


?>
<tr>
<th >Agent</th>
<th >Activity</th>
<th >TransactionNum</th>
<th>PreTaxSalary</th>


</tr>
<?php
while($d=mysqli_fetch_array($resz))
{
?>
<td><?php echo $d['Agent'];?></td>
<td><?php echo $d['Client'];?></td> 
<td><?php echo $d['TransactionNum'];?></td> 
<td><?php echo $d['PreTaxSalary'];?> gdes </td> 
</tr>
<?php
 }

 ?>
```

Comment: why did you put `sql` code in php part ? put your sql `CASE, IF ...` into your sql query `SELECT  Agent, ...`

Answer (score 0):

Well I think the biggest problem with your code is that it is NOT PHP :)

I would suggest learning how to code in PHP first.

But If you would like to jump straight to working with Mysql in PHP this tutorial could help you http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_intro.asp

Comment: Could you drop a line on which line is not PHP ?

Comment: The code has been edited 30 minuts ago... look at the original version.

Comment: Checkin:  Oops, my bad, I should've looked.

Comment: Anyway where is '$resz' comes from? It supposed to hold the result of the query. Where is the call to 'mysqli_query'?
http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php

Comment: i forgot to add this after  the query :                                                          $resz = @mysqli_query($dbc, $qryz);

Answer (score 0):

The best way to handel this code is store procedure 
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-procedure.html

Answer (score 0):

i finally found the way to do it:

```
<?php 
include_once('mysql_workbench.php'); 
$qryz="SELECT  Agent, Activity, PreTaxSalary as    
PreT, SUM(TransactionNum) as totalTransaction from  payroll_trial;
$resz = @mysqli_query($dbc, $qryz);
?>
<tr>
 <th >Agent</th>
<th>Activity</th>
<th>Price</th>
<th>Amount</th>
<th>PreTaxSalary</th>


</tr>
<?php
while($d=mysqli_fetch_array($resz))
 {

$total=$d['totalTransaction'];
switch($d['Activity'])

{

case 'Reverification(DOP)':
IF ($total < 1366)
$total= $total*11;
ElseIF ($total < 1866)
$total=  (($total-1365)*11.65)+ (1365*11);
ElseIF ($total < 2366)
$total= (($total-1865)*13.2) + (500*11.65) + (1365*11); 
Else 
$total=  (($total-2365)*13.8)+ (500*13.2) + (500*11.65)
+ (1365*11);
break;

case 'Medicaid (CS)':
IF ($total < 2731)
$total= $total*5.5;
ElseIF ($total < 1866)
$total= (($total-3231)*2730)+ (2730*5.5);
ElseIF ($total < 3731) 
$total= (($total-3230)*6.8) + (500*6) + (2730*5.5) ; 
Else 
$total=  (($total-3730)*7.2)+  (500*6.8) + (500*6) +  
(2730*5.5);
break;
case 'Eligibility Only (DDS)':

IF ($total< 2206)
$total= $total*6.81;
ElseIF ($total< 2706)
$total= (($total-2205)*6.95)+ (2205*6.81);
ElseIF ($total < 3206)
$total= (($total-2705)*7.25) + (500*6.95) + (2205*6.81) ;
Else 
$total= (($total-3205)*7.85)+ (500*7.25) + 
(500*6.95) + (2205*6.81);
break;
?>
<tr>
<td><?php echo $d['Agent'];?></td> 
<td><?php echo $d['Activity'];?></td> 
<td><?php echo $d['totalTransaction '];?> </td> 
</tr>
<td><?php echo $d['PreT'];?> </td>
```